# Phone is lagging

Tags: performance

Some apps lag on my phone. For example, Chrome, Opera Beta. But other apps are working quite normal. 
I noticed that these apps redraw almost all screen, so I believe this is somehow related to graphics.
I heard that I need to enable force GPU rendering, but it's on already. Tried to switch it off, feels like nothing changed.
What can I do with it?
My phone is HTC Incredible S and my ROM is MIUI 4.2.28, android version 4.1.2.

Comment: Why have two browsers? How many tabs do you have open in a typical browsing session?

Comment: @t0mm13b I use Chrome only to see my bookmarks on PC. And I usually open 3 or less tabs, but it lags even when I have 1 tab opened.

Answer (score 2):

When the screen redraws, that is usually a sign of low memory. Considering this device is 3 years old, has 768mb of RAM, a 1GHz single core processor and running an Android version that was never even released for the phone, lag is going to happen.

Chrome and Opera are both very memory hungry apps and since your device has a small amount of memory and an OS with unknown memory footprint and optimizations, other tabs will get purged from memory quite easily, leading to redraws when switching tabs.